# How can I replace a Wordpress website in my host's root directory with a new Wordpress website installed in a sub-directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress installations hosted by Hostgater, the first is my old site and it sits in the root directory, the second is my new site and it sits in a sub-directory called v2. I'm ready to launch my new site, so besides removing the old Wordpress files in my root directory and copying the new Wordpress files from v2  to the root, are there any other database or configuration related steps I need to take?

Thank you in advance for any help.
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the new site is fetched from /v2.

The codex should come in handy: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

You could use this tool to change all the urls in your database: (URL moved, search wordpress search and replace)

Comment: Thank you. Admittedly I just briefly perused the document and kind of winged it a bit, pretty moved just moved all the files and fixed any path issues I could find in the database. Having to re-activate the plug-ins was kind of weird, but it didn't have any negative effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export tool. It will transfer mainly your posts and content. Since you already have a setup in place. It just depends what you need to transfer. Here is the link:https://en.support.wordpress.com/export